# React layout children dynamically without unmounting

Tags: reactjs, layout, children

I have a React component that is used to layout its children according to their key. Here is what it looks like:

```
<Container focusedChildKey={this.state.focusedChildKey}>
  <Child key="child1" />
  <Child key="child2" />
  <Child key="child3" />
</Container>
```

In the container, in the `render` function I do something simple:

```
let focused = null;
let normals = [];

React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
  if (child.key === this.props.focusedChildKey) {
    focused = child
  } else {
    normals.push(child);
  }
});

return (
  <div>
   <div className="focusedChild", style={{ ... }}>
     {focused}
   </div>
   {normals}
  </div>
);
```

The problem I encounter is that whenever the `focusedChildKey` props changes on the `Container`, the focused child got unmounted and mounted again. Children in my case carry a lot of states that I lose every time one of the child get focused.

I read a lot but can't understand why it's re-mounting the whole component.

Comment: I think this answers your question https://www.huy.dev/2017-01-avoid-unnecessary-remounting-react/

Comment: Thank you I read this article but doesn't help much unfortunately. Child are components that are defined in their own classes. They may be different but they are all wrapped in a Higher Order Component.